# how to implement progress bar of file upload using jquery in asp.net?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

hi i m uploading a file and for that i have implemented aspx and .cs pages.but now i want to add progress bar only.how to do that?

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    HttpPostedFile postedFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
    string ClientFileName, ServerFileName;

    if ((FileUpload1.HasFile && FileUpload1.PostedFile != null) || txtUrl.Text!="")
    {
        lblOutput.Text = "";

            HttpPostedFile myFile = FileUpload1.PostedFile;


                    ServerFileName = System.IO.Path.Combine(ServerSavePathI, ClientFileName);


                    string serverPath = Server.MapPath(ServerFileName);

                    FileUpload1.SaveAs(serverPath);
    }
}
```

this is the code of .cs file the click event of button upload

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can implement properly using jQuery alone.  You would need to use a component like [NeatUpload](http://neatupload.codeplex.com/), which includes a server-side module to track how much data is uploaded.

Comment: ok.so now is there any other way so that i can implement it because i have implement functionality of upload using c#

Comment: If you're unable to use NeatUpload or something similar that integrates with your ASP.NET code, the only other way to get an upload progress bar is to use something Flash-based.  Some popular options are SwfUpload, Uploadify, and Flajaxian.  Personally, I've found these all to be a little unreliable in providing an accurate progress bar, and would recommend using something like NeatUpload if possible.